# Word usage in a statement

Tags: word-choice

I am trying to determine if the word *predicated* is the correct word for the following statement.

> A senior management leader in a Fortune 500 organization whose successful career was predicated on interpersonal skills and collaboration.

I would like to advise the reader that without *interpersonal skills and collaboration*, I would not have experienced the successful career that I did.

Any thoughts or alternatives?

Comment: "A senior management leader" sounds obfuscatory, or vague/unclear at best. I suggest either simplifying it to "A senior manager" or expanding it to "A senior manager and leader", whichever applies.

Answer (score 1):

*Predicated* indeed is fine.

Other alternatives you might want to consider are [**rest**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rest) and *rely*.

> "A senior management leader in a Fortune 500 organization whose successful career *rested on* interpersonal skills and collaboration."
>
> "A senior management leader in a Fortune 500 organization whose successful career *relied on* interpersonal skills and collaboration."

[**rest**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rest): to sit or lie fixed or supported; to be based or founded.

[**rely**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/rely): to depend (on); be dependent (on).

Comment: This is better; "predicated on" is a rather odd metaphor.  I
suppose the thought is that what depends on something is to it
as a predicate to its subject.  Using it if one couldn't have
thought of that one's self strikes me as a bit ridiculous,
especially if this is obvious.  It's probably ridiculous in all events.

Answer (score 1):

*Predicated* (*predicated on*) is fine as long as you mean it to mean *based* or *established* which it appears you do. I believe it requires the *on*.

There are some examples here [Examples of predicate / predicated on](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/predicate)

Comment: Yes, it does require the _on_. This is a special case of the verb _predicate_, which normally only refers to concepts and sentences, [since it's a logical term](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf). This sense of _predicated on_ (or _predicated upon_, if you want it to falute a little higher to match _predicated_) means 'is caused by (conscious application of)', and is always a compliment. Nobody predicates their failure on their unfailing stupidity, ignorance, and stubbornness; they don't see it that way.